# VueJS - event emitted - show HTML before other calculations

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Would like to:**

Show an HTML element when an event is emitted and run some calculations after the element is shown.

**But:**

The HTML element is only shown after the calculations ran.

**Strange:**

Console shows that the event callback ran before the calculations.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: false
  },

  methods: {
    showCallback() {
      console.log('showCallback');
      console.log(this.show);
      this.show = true;
      console.log(this.show);
    },
    
    start() {
      this.$emit('loading-show');

      console.log('Calculation start');

      // Do some calculations
      for (let i = 1; i < 10000000000; i++) {}

      console.log('Calculation finish');
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$on('loading-show', this.showCallback);
  },

  destroyed() {
    this.$off('loading-show', this.showCallback);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="start">Start</button>
  <h1 v-show="show">Shown</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @KGabor you should put your showCallback inside methods: {}

Comment: Hi @Birante Updated the code snippet, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `await vm.$nextTick();` - then give the browser time to breath

- with double `requestAnimationFrame`

After emiting the event, update the dom  and before blocking with calculations of any kind  skip a render  frame.

Schould be done always - in considration of low computation devices.

```js
Vue.skipFrame = function(){

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => 
    requestAnimationFrame(resolve)
    )
  })
}

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: false
  },

  methods: {
    showCallback(ctx) {
      console.log('showCallback');
      console.log(this.show);
      this.show = true;
      console.log(this.show);
    },
    
    async start() {
      this.$emit('loading-show', this);
      console.log('Calculation start');
      await this.$nextTick();
      // dom is up to date now and has to be painted
      // thus skip one frame before blocking the browser in the second
      await Vue.skipFrame();
      for (let i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) {

      }
      console.log('Calculation finish');
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$on('loading-show', this.showCallback);
  },

  destroyed() {
    this.$off('loading-show', this.showCallback);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="start">Start</button>
  <h1 v-show="show">Shown</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works but isn't there a way to replace the requestAnimationFrame calls with something (eg. with an await function call) so I would not need to wrap everything after the nextTick into lambdas?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not use a for loop for your test, use setTimeout instead.  Otherwise your UI will not update.
2. Use `v-if`, `v-else-if`, and `v-else` to show HTML based off of your state.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: false,
    done: false,
    
    showCallback: function() {
      console.log('showCallback');
      console.log(this.show);
      this.show = true;
      console.log(this.show);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    start() {
      this.done = false
      this.$emit('loading-show');

      console.log('Calculation start');

      // Do some calculations
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.done = true
        console.log('Calculation finish');}, 2000)      
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$on('loading-show', this.showCallback);
  },

  destroyed() {
    this.$off('loading-show', this.showCallback);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="start">Start</button>
  <h1 v-if=!show>Press Start</h1>
  <h1 v-else-if="!done">Processing</h1>
  <h1 v-else>Shown</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a few problems with your snippet: first I think the conditions are wrong on the "h1"s. Second, you are changing the "done" variable within the original funtion which is called on the button press (the "start" function) not in the event callback, that is why the UI got updated I think.

Comment: The snippet works, just not in StackOverflow...  If you open the snippet editor and run it you will see.

Comment: Ture, if I open it, it works but still doesn't anwer the question, how solve the showing of the UI parts on an event emit. (this is a minimal working example, in the real project they are separate components. One is running the calculations and one is trying to show the loading screen)

Comment: Pls consider that a setTimeOut approch tries to delay heavy code execution past a vue dom calulation within javascript and also a full browser render frame (html, css) - thus it creates a race condition - most time notable on mobile devices. But there are methods: `Vue->nextTick` and `Window->requestAnimationFrame` to prevent this without guessing the needed delay ;)

Comment: @Estradiaz The set timeout was replacing code to simulate work.  It is supposed to create a delay, and not be efficient.